# How to publish API hidden behind spring cloud gateway/custom gateway in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Let me briefly describe the context. Near future will bring changes which means in short introducing API Management solution for the company (large). A lot of different systems around, SOAP, REST, some other protocols.

The goal is to have one marketplace when user/customer could easily search through those mess. The case is that most of the avaliable APIS/Services are behind departments gateways, there are many of services behind such GW coupled by deparment context mostly. The main goal of GW's is to protect backend services in a way that those gateways verifies token with Identity & Authorization Provider (one common for company).

How can i publish those services which are behind those gateways? There are no swagger definition available for most of them. I have some concept idea but would be more than happy to know production solution for that case.

Answer (score 1):

By using wso2 API Manager You can publish REST, SOAP, Websocket API's and you can provide different types of authentication like OAuth2, JWT, etc.

You can provide Scope(Authorization) for each API's

If you are a beginner wso2 API Manager is shipped with Pizza Shack API for learning purpose. Start the wso2 API management server and visit https://localhost:9443/publisher with authentication admin:admin. Once you visit the publisher portal it'll guide you to publish API.

Here is the link for documentation regarding the publishing of API's https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/API+Publishing

> How can i publish those services which are behind those gateways?
>   There are no swagger definition available for most of them. I have
>   some concept idea but would be more than happy to know production
>   solution for that case.

The swagger definition is another way of publishing API in API manager if you have already swagger definition you can just import. But whatever API's you'll publish in API manager inside it stores as a Swagger definition.

If you are using Wso2 API manager for Production use please refer the following:https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Product+Administration which will describe the necessary changes and fine-tuning to be done for production.

Further if you can have multitenant setup, in which each tenant will have a separate store which is a great feature https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/08/article-multi-tenant-api-management-with-wso2-api-manager/